# Possible to Access build file in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, build

I'm making a project in IntelliJ.  Whenever I hit "run" and my code is executed I assume there must be a build file that IntelliJ is using in the background to do this.  Is there a way to access this build file?

If not how would one go about sharing a project developed with IntelliJ, on say Github for example.  Would you need to create your own build file with a tool like ant to be able to do this? It seems like there must be a simpler answer.

Comment: Can you not just share the underlying java file(s) and people can just compile the file themselves?

Comment: That becomes impractical for a large project where code is separated in a directory structure, packages, etc..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no build file as such. The build is controlled by the project configuration, which is stored in the .idea directory. You can share that directory on GitHub, as long as you exclude your personal settings (workspace.xml and tasks.xml).

Comment: How would one go about running the project then? Would they need to use IntelliJ also or is there a command to run the .idea directory files needed to build the project from the terminal?

Comment: They will need to use IntelliJ as well. You can mark some run configurations in IntelliJ IDEA as "shared", and then they will be stored in the .idea directory as well and will be available to your collaborators.